# Slow performance with SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm having some issues with this query running in a timely manner with my 'LineItemsMap' table grows to about a million lines.  Any suggestions on indexes I could create or just better logic with the query would be greatly appreciated.

```
    select 
      Id, 
      [Description],
      SUM(CASE WHEN t1.compliant = 1  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Compliant,
      SUM(CASE WHEN t1.compliant = 0  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as NonCompliant,
      LastChecked 
from lineitems as t0
      left outer join lineitemsmap as t1 on t0.id = t1.lineitemid
      left outer join art_blob as t2 on t2.art_blob_id = t1.blobid
      left outer join art_asset as t3 on t3.art_asset_id = t2.art_asset_id
      left outer join lineitemexceptions as t4 on t4.assetid = t3.art_asset_id and t4.lineitemid = t1.lineitemid
where t0.active = 1 and t4.assetid is null
group by t0.id, t0.[description], t0.lastchecked
```

Here is a link to the execute plan saved in XML:  http://codepaste.net/5xcpcw
Here is a link to the table structure: http://codepaste.net/pnqx6e

Comment: What kind of indexes do you already have? What is the structure of those tables involved?

Comment: @marc_s mostly just default indexes.  I included a link to the table structure scripts.

Comment: You may have more luck at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Active should be indexed on lineitems
2. LineItemId should be indexed on LineItemsMap
3. AssetId should be indexed on LineItemExceptions
4. art_asset_id should be indexed on art_blob

I didn't see any others. Any field used for a join should always be indexed. Having indexes on your fields from your where clause can help a lot too, but you should be cautious about too many indexes.

Comment: Based on the schema dump, #2, definitely. Aside from the fact that you can't index a bit column, an index on `Active` won't do anything since there's only two possible values, unless it would filter out most of the table (e.g. 10,000 active, 990,000 inactive rows)

Comment: You can index bit columns. Or as I would prefer to see it implemented, as a secondary field on an index,  but I don't know the specifics of the data.

Comment: My goodness.  That definitely worked.  Thank you very much.  I went from 12 seconds to load to about a second.

Comment: @SpectralGhost there is no point of indexing Active due to the fact that it is bit field, there are only two possible values for this field {1,0}

Comment: @010001100110000101110010011010 Your assertion can be correct in certain cases and incorrect in others; this is more dependent on the data at hand. The insert hit on the index could outweigh the possible read gains. But like I said, I normally do not use bits as the only field of an index. In the case provided in the question, it probably is not helping much, if at all. This is why we test.